# What are these "host" directories?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, disk, fdisk, vmware-workstation

I'm using Oracle Linux 7.6, which is a distribution based on RHEL 7.6. The following testing should be the same on RHEL 7.6 or other RHEL 7.6 based distributions.

I'm running the Oracle Linux 7.6 server in VMware Workstation on Windows 10. What I'm trying to do is to add a disk to the Linux guest virtual machine without rebooting the Linux server. I googled around and found this page: https://rahsupport.wordpress.com/2017/08/10/vmware-add-disk-to-linux-without-rebooting-the-vm/. Basically, what it does is:

- Add the disk from VMware Workstation to the Linux VM
- Go to `/sys/class/scsi_host/`
- Run `echo '- - -' > host1/scan`
- Then by running `fdisk -l`, you can see the newly added disk

I tested it on in my environment. There are three such host directories and each of them has a `scan` file in it:

```
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 0 Aug 24 22:49 .
drwxr-xr-x. 54 root root 0 Aug 24 22:49 ..
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 Aug 24 22:49 host0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/ata1/host0/scsi_host/host0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 Aug 24 22:49 host1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/ata2/host1/scsi_host/host1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 0 Aug 24 22:49 host2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/scsi_host/host2
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]#
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# ls -la */scan
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Aug 24 22:50 host0/scan
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Aug 24 22:50 host1/scan
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Aug 24 22:50 host2/scan
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]#
```

Originally, the Linux server can't recognize the disk:

```
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d3e78

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      976895      487424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          976896  2059401215  1029212160   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      2059401216  2101344255    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda4      2101344256  2147483647    23069696    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      2101348352  2143289343    20970496   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      2143291392  2147483647     2096128   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

But when I run `echo '- - -' > host0/scan`, the disk showed up:

```
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# echo '- - -' > host0/scan
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d3e78

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      976895      487424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          976896  2059401215  1029212160   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      2059401216  2101344255    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda4      2101344256  2147483647    23069696    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      2101348352  2143289343    20970496   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      2143291392  2147483647     2096128   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]#
```

I reverted my Linux VM to its original state to test again. This time it showed that `echo '- - -' > host1/scan` doesn't work, but `echo '- - -' > host2/scan` works.

```
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d3e78

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      976895      487424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          976896  2059401215  1029212160   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      2059401216  2101344255    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda4      2101344256  2147483647    23069696    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      2101348352  2143289343    20970496   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      2143291392  2147483647     2096128   82  Linux swap / Solaris
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# echo '- - -' > host1/scan
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d3e78

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      976895      487424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          976896  2059401215  1029212160   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      2059401216  2101344255    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda4      2101344256  2147483647    23069696    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      2101348352  2143289343    20970496   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      2143291392  2147483647     2096128   82  Linux swap / Solaris
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# echo '- - -' > host2/scan
root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d3e78

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      976895      487424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          976896  2059401215  1029212160   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      2059401216  2101344255    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda4      2101344256  2147483647    23069696    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      2101348352  2143289343    20970496   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      2143291392  2147483647     2096128   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

root:[/sys/class/scsi_host]#
```

My question is, what's these **host** directories? Why `echo '- - -' > host0/scan` and `echo '- - -' > host2/scan` will make Linux server recognize the disk, but `echo '- - -' > host1/scan` can't?

Btw, I'm pretty new in Linux and still learning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different `host` directories correspond to different disk controllers. What controllers map to depends on the technology involved; AHCI SATA hosts have one host per port, NVMe uses one host per controller, etc. The exact situation in your case will depend on your VM setup.

Basically what this means is that you should rescan all hosts.